# Trusted Web Activity - Address bar not hide - no app deep persmission

Tags: android, android-activity, progressive-web-apps, deep-linking, trusted

i am testing PWA (TWA) to APK and i have a problem with address bar still visible in that app. I think i have a problem with App linking.

i have tested it there: https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator 
and it say: No app deep linking permission found for cz.svetandroida.app at svetandroida.cz.

Hosting domain: svetandroida.cz

App package name: cz.svetandroida.app

fingerprint: 2D:C8:DA:46:31:77:D3:20:27:D9:1A:8A:17:26:24:9D:79:5E:7C:7A:7D:22:86:6C:21:CD:DE:49:B9:09:7B:6A

My Json is working and but still have an error. 
https://svetandroida.cz/.well-known/assetlinks.json

Do you have any idea? :)

Comment: I had this issue and after waiting 5 minutes and then reentering all my info into the generator it worked.  Hopefully this comment will help someone.